# How to fix imagick on gravityzone?

Tags: networking, package-management

I'm installing gravityzone server on my Ubuntu. When I try to install web console it gives me and error.

The problem is it can't install `php7.4-imagick`. I tried to install it manually and I got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.4-imagick : Depends: libmagickcore-6.q16-6 (>= 8:6.9.10.2) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libmagickwand-6.q16-6 (>= 8:6.9.10.2) but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: ghostscript but it is not installable
                  Recommends: ttf-dejavu-core but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any help?

Comment: Try to install `libmagickcore-6.q16-6` manually using `sudo apt install libmagickcore-6.q16-6`, then try `php7.4-imagick` again. At the very least, `apt` will tell you *why* `libmagickcore-6.q16-6` cannot be installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)